# Position of text in responsive block

Tags: html, css, responsive

There is a block with text. I need to see text in it a little to the left than I have now and it is needed to be responsive. I wrote this:

```css
.sliderr__item .slid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/*END*/

.sliderr {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderr__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sliderr__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderr"><br>
  <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 250px;" class="slid">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p><br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<span>21.08.2018</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to have some space between `Lorem Ipsum text` and date `21.08.2018` but I have some problems with that.

Comment: Set your `span` as `display: inline-block` and apply the desired amount of `margin-left`

Comment: @Jake it did not help(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sliderr__item .slid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/*END*/

.sliderr {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderr__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sliderr__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.sliderr .date {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderr"><br>
  <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 250px;" class="slid">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p><br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum <span class="date">21.08.2018</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a regular space, simply add a space in your HTML code.

If you want a bigger space between "Lorem Ipsum" and the date, set the span to `display: inline-block` (its default value being `inline`) and apply the desired amount of `margin-left`

Answer (score 0):

## Before :

[image]

## After :

[image]

## Solution A :

You can add space. Replace

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum<span>21.08.2018</span></p>
```

By :

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum <span>21.08.2018</span></p>
```

## Solution B :

With css and before content.

HTML :

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum<span class="bspace">21.08.2018</span></p>
```

CSS :

```
.bspace:before {
    content:" ";
}
```

Like that :

```css
.bspace:before {
  content: " ";
}

.sliderr__item .slid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/*END*/

.sliderr {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliderr__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sliderr__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderr"><br>
  <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
    <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
      <div style="height: 250px;" class="slid">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p><br>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span></p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum<span class="bspace">21.08.2018</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```